# how to display an alternate message ,if particular record is not available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

presently i am playing with rails3.Can it possible to show a message like"Sorry , this data is not available", in view if we do not have that data in record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to...

```
class ModelController < ApplicationController

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      begin
        @model = Model.find(params[:id])
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound 
        format.html { render :text => "Sorry , this data is not available" }
      end
    end
  end

end
```